# Timeline to ask postdoc interview outcome

Tags: postdocs, interview

I was interviewed for a postdoc position and I was so nervous but tried to respond to the question the best I can. I think the interview was OK but not to the best of my expectation. They asked me when can I start though. It was a 15 min presentation and 15 min Q&A. At the end I asked them questions but didn't ask when will I hear back from them and they didn't tell me either. Is it polite if I ask them a week after the interview (if there is no news sooner)? Or should I wait, say, at least 2 weeks after interview?

Answer (score 1):

It is fine to ask for an update now, or to wait. But, unless there is some other option that makes early notice necessary, I'd suggest waiting for a bit.

In any request, however, it might be good to express, again, your interest (strong interest) in the position.

If you don't get a quick answer, don't fret over it. These things can take time.

Comment: Thanks Buffy, at the moment I don't have any other options, so maybe I will wait until next week. Just curious about how long is on average applicants heard back from the PI. Is early news tend to be good news for example?